# Does a ref unref its ref contents?

Tags: vuejs3

<sup>Sorry for the weird title</sup>

I am using Vue3 with [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/products/highcharts/). I need to have a reactive Object that is being passed to the chart (and when its contents change the chart is updated). It works great.

At some point I wanted to format the tooltip which appears when hovering over data. This is done in the configuration object this way:

```
const phishingMap = ref<Record<number, Result>>({})

const chartOptions = ref({
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
      console.log(this.x)
      console.log(phishingMap.value[this.x])
      console.log(phishingMap[this.x])
      return phishingMap[this.x].Name + '<br>' + phishingMap[this.x].Total
    }
  }
})
```

I was intilally returning `phishingMap.value[this.x].Name` and was having an error on `phishingMap.value`, to being defined. Working with Vue for some time, I got used to add `.value` to my reactive variables so I was quite lost.

I then added a few debug data per the code above. To my surprise, the proper way to address the Object is with a bare `phishingMap` and not `phishingMap.value`.

It is a case of the inception of a `ref` variable in a `ref` variable. I experimentally found out that the inner `ref` should be addressed directly and not by `.value` - what is the reason for that?

Comment: Accessing a ref from a function inside another ref does not change the way you access it. Did you put the phishingMap ref as property on the chartOptions ref? In this case, the inner ref gets unwrapped. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @MoritzRingler: I am not sure I understand your comment - what is missing in the example code in my question so that I can clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing a ref from a function inside another ref does not change the way you access it. You still need `.value` to get to the ref's content. Your code should give you an "cannot access property on undefined" error. Compare it with the code in the snipped (consistently using `.value`):

```js
const { ref } = Vue;
const phishingMap = ref({})

const chartOptions = ref({
  tooltip: {
    x: 'foo',
    formatter: function () {
      console.log('property (x) is', this.x)
      console.log('phishingMap.value is', phishingMap.value)
      console.log('resolved property is', phishingMap.value[this.x])
      return phishingMap.value[this.x].Name + '<br>' + phishingMap.value[this.x].Total
    }
  }
})

phishingMap.value.foo = {Name: 'le Name', Total: 'le total'}
console.clear()
console.log('returned value is', chartOptions.value.tooltip.formatter())
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

My guess is that you are overriding the ref itself instead of its value somewhere, for example when you load `phishingMap` (are you sure you instantiate it with `const`)?

```
phishingMap = await loadPhishingMap() // <--- phishingMap will not be a ref after this
```

Comment: Thank you - yes, somehow I managed to mess it up and ended up inferring the variable. After close inspection, everything is back to normal.